# Рекурсивная функция умножения значений массива

Tags: рекурсия, массивы, c++

Пишу задачу нахождение произведения элементов массива рекурсивным методом.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

double mnoz(int *x,int n)
    {
     if (n ==1) return fabs(x[n]);
     int p=mnoz(x,n-1);
     return fabs(x[n]*p);
    }
void main()
   {
    int i,n;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Input n=";
    cin>>n;
    int* a=new int[n];
    for (i=1;i<n;i++) a[i]=-i;
    cout<<mnoz(a,n);
    // delete[] a;
    getch();
   }
```

Проблема в том что выводит по странному ввожу 7 выводит 0. Ввожу после 6 выводит нормальный ответ.

Comment: задание p=П|a[i]|
где П от 1 до n
элементы массива a[]<0

Comment: `<conio.h>`, ура, мы в каменном веке!

Comment: А вы знаете, что в C++ массивы индексируются, начиная с нуля?

---
Попробуйте самостоятельно сформулировать словами, что именно делает функция `mnoz`. Ошибка тут же станет ясна.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Перестаньте писать на древнем диалекте 96 года (если я правильно определил, что это Borland c++ 5.0). Иначе Вы никому не нужны будете кроме парочки вузов в глубинке. Также будете регулярно натыкаться на "особенности реализации".

Посмотрите на немного причесанный вариант и сравните с своим.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double mnoz(int *x,int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return fabs(x[n]);
    int p=mnoz(x,n-1);
    return fabs(x[n]*p);
}

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    std::cout<<"Input n=";
    std::cin>>n;
    int* a=new int[n];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        a[i]=-i;
    std::cout << mnoz(a,n-1);
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Итак, почему так правильно.

- правильные заголовочные файлы.
- main должен быть типа int и, возможно иметь два (в некоторых компиляторах - три) параметра.
- массивы, как было замечено выше, начинаются  с нулевого индекса, а индекс последнего элемента - размер минус 1.
- не освобождать ресурсы в такой маленькой программе возможно оправданно, но раз уж написали, то зачем коментировать?
- так как `mnoz(a,n);` получала размер массива, то она пыталась обратиться к элементу за пределами массива. А это может приводить к самым причудливым результатам. Но обычно с следующего за последним элементом читается мусор. Что и приводит к самым различным результатам.
- в условии в функции я оставил все таки проверку на равенство 1. Элемент с нулевым индексом оставим в покое. Если его значение учитывать, что результат функции будет всегда предсказуем - 0.
- возможно (а скорее всего оно так и будет), этот код не скомпилируется Вашим древним компилятором. Но оно так и должно быть. Скачайте себе любой нормальный компилятор, хотя бы бесплатный от Майкрософта (он ещё и с IDE в нагрузку, для Ваших задач предостаточно).

Comment: > main должен быть типа int и, возможно иметь два (в некоторых компиляторах - три) параметра.

Можно забить болт и писать `void main()` или `void main(void)`. 90% компилеров это съедят.

> правильные заголовочные файлы.

+1

Comment: @KoVadim, а как вы оперделили что это Borland C++ 5? Просто любопытно:)

Comment: Понятия не имею:) Просто интересно на чем основывался @KoVadim

Comment: Вероятно на <iostream.h>. И на <conio.h>

Comment: первое - это conio.h и утверждение автора, что все компилируется. Второе - это то, что нет `std::` - а этим страдало не так много компиляторов.

> Можно забить болт и писать void main() или void main(void). 90% компилеров это съедят.

Ни последний gcc (4.7.2), ни clang (3.2) не хотят переваривать без int в начале. Еще бы студию проверить...

Comment: @KoVadim `std::`... Когда там namespace появилось-то? Во втором Страутрупе или где? До того все страдали.

Comment: вначале все делали как хотели. Но из доступных компиляторов, которые сейчас доступны широкой публике это один с немногих.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как научили так и решаю задачи. Мы используем turbo c++.
Учусь в угату. Вам бы видеть нашего препода по программированию, тогда сразу все вопросы в плане диалекта программирования отпадут.

Comment: значит нужно учиться решать правильно. или не решать вообще. А пинять на преподавателя не нужно. Нужно брать и писать.

Comment: @Adrug

     Вам бы видеть нашего препода по программированию

А что мы Вам плохого сделали? (1). Выбор трупного си++ может быть обусловлен слабостью матбазы... (2)

А вот "как учили", тут присоединяюсь к @KoVadim -- это уже Ваши проблемы. В пределах конкретного лягушатника это может сойти за отмазку, но в любой другой луже приниматься не будет. Тем более, как я подозреваю, доступ в интернет у Вас есть. (или это у меня глюки?)

Comment: На тот момент пока я не получил ответа от пользователя @KoVadim, не предполагал иных методов решения, считал что все реализуется именно так. Нет необходимости меня обвинять в том что я не знаю того си,к которому вы привыкли. @KoVadim ну а по вашему чем я здесь занимаюсь? На мой вопрос вы дали ясный полный ответ, который меня вполне устроил. Соответственно я научился по новому решать задачи.
"А что мы Вам плохого сделали?" какими словами я вам дал повод думать так?
"В пределах конкретного лягушатника ..."
т.е. вы @alexlz когда только начинали программировать на с++ сразу писали все без ошибок?

Comment: @Adrug Насчёт плохого -- я Вас уже цитировал. Насчёт ошибок -- я и сейчас их допускаю (1), да и на C++ не писал и не пишу (2).

А то, что этот сайт в первую очередь именно для обучения и предназначен, так никто и не спорит. Если чем-то обидел, приношу извинения.